# C# Proxy checker application

Tags: c#, proxy

I want to make a proxy checker in C# but I don't know how to do it to be honest.

I want it to let it look like this:
[image]

Could someone please send me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you provide some more information on what code you already tried or what you have in mind? Do you want to setup a proxy to monitor internet traffic from your pc (ip:port) to outgoing connection (ip:port)?

Comment: I have no code yet, it is a mockup what i made. ( the imgur link)

Comment: Then please provide an explenation what you define or expect to have, is it something like `netstat -ano` in command line windows, where you get a list of connections on your machine? with Protocol, Local Address (ip:port), Foreign Address (ip:port), State, ProcessId?

Comment: I want a windows application where i can add proxys from my C drive ( for example proxies.txt), then it will set all proxies in the datagridview and will check them on a site, for example google.com. It will go to the website, will check how fast it goes to the website and if it goes to the website it will say: true. if not it wil say false.

Comment: Ok, I am still unsure what a proxy means to you... Google.com isn't a proxy. What is a proxy for you? What is the definition, how would you describe what a proxy is.
Reading a file from disk, is that something that you have implemented already, or is that also something you're looking help with? **Please be very specific and detailed WHAT it is that YOU want help with, every step, every detail** - otherwise no one will understand or be able to help you :/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXT3AulBcgw Like this. But i want it in C# visual studio

Comment: Never mind i think the video explains itself, Thanks for ur help anyways!

Comment: Ok, I get what you're after ;). But since you've seend the video, I guess it's self explenatory now :)....

Comment: Hey, can u please help me again, the video didn't help me because it wasn't C#

Comment: there isn't much different in C# <-> VB.Net. The language/syntax differs a bit, but the libraries and classes they use are the same. If you're familiar with C# - you'll be able to read VB.Net code and port it.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Isn't there a video or something ? ( for C#) if not i just gonna try that other vid.